# Concatenate String to Evernote Markup Language (ENML) in python

Tags: python, xml, evernote

I am looking to add a string containing the user's text input to the note.content of my note. After reading, I have found how to add resources, but I don't want the resource to be an attachment, I want it to be the actual text.

Here is some of the code:

```
    title= self.textEditTitle.text()
    body= self.textEditBody.text()        

    auth_token = "secret stuff!"

    client = EvernoteClient(token=auth_token, sandbox=True)

    note_store = client.get_note_store()

    nBody = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
    nBody += "<!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM \"http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd\">"
    nBody += "<en-note>%s</en-note>" % body

    note = Types.Note()
    note.title = title
    note.content= nBody
```

Any advice would be great, as I'm just starting out with this api and it looks like it's full of potential once I figure it out! Here is what I have been mostly reading from: http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/cloud/chapters/ENML.php

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. First of all, I was using a QString object, not a normal string object. I casted the QString as a string, and separated the content so I concatenated the body variable by itself. I also encoded the string into xmlcharrefreplace, but I am still reading about that. Nevertheless, it works. Here is a clipping of the code:

```
    body= str(self.textEditBody.text())
    auth_token = "secret!"
    client = EvernoteClient(token=auth_token, sandbox=True)
    note_store = client.get_note_store()

    nBody = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
    nBody += "<!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM \"http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd\">"
    nBody += "<en-note>"
    nBody += body.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
    nBody += "</en-note>"
```